# Simple MATLAB Simulink sample in MATLAB does not work when I try to run it. Why?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to do an example in MATLAB Simulink documentation.

Here is the link:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/gs/bq5iw8a.html

I did exactly what the documentation said, but when I run it, it said:

```
"Input port 1 of 'simple_test_model/Sine Wave Function' is not connected."
```

But the documentation does not say anything about the input of Sine Wave Function.
What should I do so that I can simulate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Sine Wave](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/sinewave.html) block documentation says

> This block is the same as the Sine
>   Wave Function block that appears in
>   the Math Operations library. If you
>   select Use external source for the
>   Time parameter in the block dialog
>   box, you get the Sine Wave Function
>   block.

Switch the *Sine Wave* block parameter for *Time* back to `Use simulation time`.